# How to read the site url/ parameter in python

Tags: python, flask

Ok so i have a python app say for example `www.example.com`.Suppose i hit a url like `www.exmaple.com/function1` then is it possible to read `function1` inside the python app

Here is my python code

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    return 'Hello World --  jay!'

@app.route('/fun')
def fun():
    return 'have func!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: what is the url you wanna hit? did you mean: www.example.com/function1 ?

Comment: You need to define a rule that will match either `function1` or, a generic rule to match all unknown patterns. As you have written your code, you don't have such a rule so browsing `www.example.com/function1` will lead to a 404 page.

Comment: i know that...but is there a way to define a generic rule to handle all /parameters and read that /parameter

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: http://publish.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/<func>')
def fun(func):
    return 'have func :' + func + "!"
```